# jQuery UI resizable handles don't stay in the middle of the line

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/dfvpgcq4/4/) I have a jQuery UI resizable rectangle with handles. The problem is that when I resize the rect, sometimes the handles don't stay in the middle, see in the picture below that the line divides the handle 75% instead of 50%. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

[image]

```
#elementResizable {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;

}
#nwgrip, #negrip, #swgrip, #segrip, #ngrip, #egrip, #sgrip, #wgrip {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: red;
}
#nwgrip {
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
}
#negrip{
     top: -3px;
     right: -3px;
}
#swgrip{
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
}
#segrip{
     bottom: -3px;
     right:-3px;
}
#ngrip{
     top: -3px;
    left: calc(50% - 3px);
}
#sgrip{
     bottom: -3px;
    left: calc(50% - 3px);
}
#wgrip{
     left:-3px;
     top:calc(50% - 3px);
}
#egrip{
     right:-3px;
     top:calc(50% - 3px);
}


<div id='elementResizable'>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" id="egrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>
</div>


$('#elementResizable').resizable({
    handles: {
        'nw': '#nwgrip',
        'ne': '#negrip',
        'sw': '#swgrip',
        'se': '#segrip',
        'n': '#ngrip',
        'e': '#egrip',
        's': '#sgrip',
        'w': '#wgrip'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is only a rendering / visual issue. When I inspect the element, I can see if the height is 40 px, the South Grip is at a position of 37 px.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/u5pv79ga/13/

**JavaScript**

```
$('#elementResizable').resizable({
  handles: {
    'nw': '#nwgrip',
    'ne': '#negrip',
    'sw': '#swgrip',
    'se': '#segrip',
    'n': '#ngrip',
    'e': '#egrip',
    's': '#sgrip',
    'w': '#wgrip',
  },
  resize: function(e, ui) {
    $(".log").html("W: " + ui.size.width + ", H: " + ui.size.height + ", L: " + $("#sgrip").offset().left + ", T: " + $("#sgrip").position().top);
  }
});
```

I did notice, that sometimes, the handles will hit a half pixel when being resized. This might contribute to the minor visual difference that is seen.